# Sequences properties on $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the following affirmations are equivalent for some sequence $(x_n) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$:

a) $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty } |x_k| \to \infty $

b) $(x_k)$ does not have a convergent subsequence

c) For all bounded set $L \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, the set K$\,=\{k \in \mathbb{N} \, | \, x_k \in L \}  $ is finite.

For (a) $\to$ (b) we just show that $(x_n)$ is not bounded, so the subsequences cannot be bounded as well.

But (b) $\to$ (c) and (c) $\to$ (a)  I cannot proceed.

Any leads?

Comment: Have you heard of the notion of compactness?

Comment: b) implies c) is Bolzano Weierstrass theorem and for c) implies a) consider $L=\{x:\|x\| \leq N\}$.

Comment: Arthur, in that section of the book I'm using, compactness is not defined yet.
I'll look for it, thanks.

Comment: Kavi, thanks a lot!